# How to read nested array JSON file and store into Dictionary object

Tags: javascript, json, nested

I have the following JSON config file. I would like to read the JSON file and store into Dictionary object using Java-script.

```
{
    "DefaultTime": 10,
    "ExpetTime": 30,
    "Environment": "QA",
    "DefaultBrowser": "CHROME"
    "_Envi": [
        {
            "PP": [
                {
                    "Server1": "https://login.com",
                    "UserName": "user1",
                    "Password": "pass1",
                    "UserFullName": "userName1",
                    "UserEmail": "user@gmail.com",
                    "User2Name": "user1",
                    "User2FullName": "userName2",
                    "User2Password": "pass1",
                    "User3FullName": "user3",
                    "User3Name": "userName3",
                    "User4Name": "user4",
                    "User4FullName": "userName4",
                    "User4Email": "user4@gmail.com;"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "QA": [
                {
                    "Server": "https://gmail.com",
                    "UserName": "user1",
                    "Password": "pass1",
                    "UserFullName": "userName1",
                    "UserEmail": "user1@gmail.com",
                    "User2Name": "user2",
                    "User2Password": "pass1",
                    "User2FullName": "userName2",
                    "User3Name": "user3",
                    "User3FullName": "userName3",
                    "User4Name": "user4",
                    "User5Name": "userName4",
                    "Password4": "pass2",
                    "User4FullName": "user4",
                    "User5FullName": "user5"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "PROD": [
                {
                    "Server": "https://pro.login.com",
                    "UserName": "user1",
                    "Password": "pass1",
                    "UserFullName": "userName1",
                    "UserEmail": "user1@gmail.com",
                    "User2Name": "user2",
                    "User2FullName": "userName2",
                    "User2Password": "pass1",
                    "User3Name": "user3",
                    "User3FullName": "Username3",
                    "User4Name": "user4",
                    "User4FullName": "UserName4",
                    "User4Email": "user4@gmail.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]        
}
```

In the above JSON, I need few environment specific values based on user selection.
If  **"Environment": "PP",**  it should need to store following values in to dictionary object.

```
{
    "_Envi": [
        {
            "PP": [
                {
                    "Server1": "https://login.com",
                    "UserName": "user1",
                    "Password": "pass1",
                    "UserFullName": "userName1",
                    "UserEmail": "user@gmail.com",
                    "User2Name": "user1",
                    "User2FullName": "userName2",
                    "User2Password": "pass1",
                    "User3FullName": "user3",
                    "User3Name": "userName3",
                    "User4Name": "user4",
                    "User4FullName": "userName4",
                    "User4Email": "user4@gmail.com;"
                }
            ]
        }
    ] 
}
```

Comment: please add your code. what goes wrong?

Comment: what have you tried? Do you need help with reading a JSON file into objects so you can process it, do you need help with syntax for selecting specific elements from the object? When we read JSON into objects, they are effectively dictionaries already so it is not clear what you need from us.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in JavaScript by reading the JSON file, parsing it, and storing the environment-specific values in a dictionary object:

```js
function readJSONFile() {
  const jsonContent = `{
    "DefaultTime": 10,
    "ExpetTime": 30,
    "Environment": "QA",
    "DefaultBrowser": "CHROME",
    "_Envi": [
      {
        "PP": [
          {
            "Server1": "https://login.com",
            "UserName": "user1",
            "Password": "pass1",
            "UserFullName": "userName1",
            "UserEmail": "user@gmail.com",
            "User2Name": "user1",
            "User2FullName": "userName2",
            "User2Password": "pass1",
            "User3FullName": "user3",
            "User3Name": "userName3",
            "User4Name": "user4",
            "User4FullName": "userName4",
            "User4Email": "user4@gmail.com;"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "QA": [
          {
            "Server": "https://gmail.com",
            "UserName": "user1",
            "Password": "pass1",
            "UserFullName": "userName1",
            "UserEmail": "user1@gmail.com",
            "User2Name": "user2",
            "User2Password": "pass1",
            "User2FullName": "userName2",
            "User3Name": "user3",
            "User3FullName": "userName3",
            "User4Name": "user4",
            "User5Name": "userName4",
            "Password4": "pass2",
            "User4FullName": "user4",
            "User5FullName": "user5"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "PROD": [
          {
            "Server": "https://pro.login.com",
            "UserName": "user1",
            "Password": "pass1",
            "UserFullName": "userName1",
            "UserEmail": "user1@gmail.com",
            "User2Name": "user2",
            "User2FullName": "userName2",
            "User2Password": "pass1",
            "User3Name": "user3",
            "User3FullName": "Username3",
            "User4Name": "user4",
            "User4FullName": "UserName4",
            "User4Email": "user4@gmail.com"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }`;

  return JSON.parse(jsonContent);
}

function getEnvironmentValues(environment) {
  const jsonObject = readJSONFile(); // Replace this with actual reading from file
  const environmentValues = {};

  if (jsonObject._Envi) {
    const specificEnv = jsonObject._Envi.find(env => env[environment]);
    if (specificEnv) {
      environmentValues[environment] = specificEnv[environment];
    }
  }

  return environmentValues;
}

// Usage: Pass the environment as an argument to get the specific values
const selectedEnvironment = "PP";
const environmentDictionary = getEnvironmentValues(selectedEnvironment);
console.log(environmentDictionary);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet to get your required data:

```
const filteredData = data._Envi.map((dict) => {
if(Object.keys(dict)[0] === "PP"){
    return {"_Envi": [
            {
                "PP": data._Envi[0].PP
            }
        ]
    };
}
});

console.log(filteredData[0])

// Here is the Result
{ _Envi: [ { PP: [Array] } ] } // PP array contain the values
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Your JSON data
var jsonData = {
    "DefaultTime": 10,
    "ExpetTime": 30,
    "Environment": "QA",
    "DefaultBrowser": "CHROME",
    "_Envi": [
        {
            "PP": [
                {
                    "Server1": "https://login.com",
                    "UserName": "user1",
                    "Password": "pass1",
                    "UserFullName": "userName1",
                    "UserEmail": "user@gmail.com",
                    "User2Name": "user1",
                    "User2FullName": "userName2",
                    "User2Password": "pass1",
                    "User3FullName": "user3",
                    "User3Name": "userName3",
                    "User4Name": "user4",
                    "User4FullName": "userName4",
                    "User4Email": "user4@gmail.com;"
                }
            ]
        },
        // ... (other elements in '_Envi' array)
    ]
};

// Function to get the selected element from '_Envi'
function getSelectedElement(selectionValue) {
    var selectedElement = {};
    jsonData._Envi.forEach(function (enviElement) {
        if (enviElement[selectionValue]) {
            selectedElement[selectionValue] = [enviElement[selectionValue]];
        }
    });
    return selectedElement;
}

// Example: Pass 'PP' to get the element of 'PP' from '_Envi'
var selectedResult = getSelectedElement('PP');

// Convert the result to JSON string with indentation
var resultJsonString = JSON.stringify(selectedResult, null, 4);

// Output the result
console.log(resultJsonString);
```

pass your selection item in getSelectedElement('')

I hope this will work out